# How to Make PDF document for free?

Tags: pdf

I never pay for Adobe products and I would like to make a PDF doc.  Is it possible somehow to do it for free?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/) allows you to save documents to a PDF. On Mac OS X, it is also possible to "print" literally anything to a PDF (just hit COMMAND+P, then use the PDF button to save the file). If you are into programming, you can use LaTeX to write your document and then use pdflatex to create a PDF.

If you are trying to write a program that generates PDFs, the source code of LaTeX  or OpenOffice should include a bit of code to generate PDF documents. There are probably other libraries to do this.

Answer (score 2):

For most case, I use pdfCreator.
It install a virtual printer you can use all of your programs.
When you print with this virtual printer it generates a pdf file corresponding to the same outpout you get with your printer :)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/

Answer (score 1):

Check out PDF995 - it installs as a printer driver, so you can go and "print" to it and it takes the output and makes it into a PDF.

Comment: A similar tool to this is CutePDF, which is also free. http://cutepdf.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to convert a MS Office file to PDF? If so, you could use OpenOffice.

Comment: just trying to write text and save as PDF